# Retrieve range of data per each value and sort them

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
Class     Value
Abrir     15
Abrir     9
Abrir     29
Abrir     13
Salvar    10
Salvar    6
Salvar    9
Shift     16
Shift     12
Shift     10
Shift     17
```

I want to retrieve the range of values for each class and sort them based on the smallest value such the following:

```
Salvar 6 - 10
Abrir  9 - 29
Shift  10 - 17
```

I tried to do it but I couldn't. Can someone help me in doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to group by 'Class' and `paste` the `range` of 'Value' and `arrange` if necessary

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Class) %>%
   summarise(Range = paste(range(Value), collapse = ' - ')) %>%
   arrange(parse_number(Range))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Class  Range  
#  <chr>  <chr>  
#1 Salvar 6 - 10 
#2 Abrir  9 - 29 
#3 Shift  10 - 17
```

Or place it in a `list`

```
aggregate(Value ~ Class, df1, FUN = range)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Class = c("Abrir", "Abrir", "Abrir", "Abrir", 
 "Salvar", "Salvar", "Salvar", "Shift", "Shift", "Shift", "Shift"
 ), Value = c(15L, 9L, 29L, 13L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 16L, 12L, 10L, 17L
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution with `min` and `max`, i.e.

```
df2 <- aggregate(Value ~ Class, df1, function(i) paste0(min(i), ' - ', max(i)))

#   Class   Value
#1  Abrir  9 - 29
#2 Salvar  6 - 10
#3  Shift 10 - 17
```

We can use a simple regex in order to sort the resulting data frame, i.e. (considering the above data frame is called `df2`)

```
df2[order(as.numeric(gsub('([0-9]+)\\s-\\s[0-9]+', '\\1', df2$Value))),]

#   Class   Value
#2 Salvar  6 - 10
#1  Abrir  9 - 29
#3  Shift 10 - 17
```

Comment: That looks awesome but what about ordering them based on the smallest value?